# How do I get KATE to start the command prompt on a new line after running a c program through it

Tags: kde, kate

[the command prompt lines starts immediately after the code output ( sum = 5 ) and not on the next line...any way I can change that ??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7d29.png)

Comment: Fix your program to print a newline at the end of output.

Comment: If you change the $PS1 you'll find yourself wasting a lot of screen space (ie. having a blank line after every program that finishes on a blank line).  The prior comment is the *conformity* response  (ie. convention since the early 1970s).

Comment: Workedd....*feels silly.

Thanks a lot